# How much memory is a specific user using

Tags: users, memory

Is it possible to find out how much memory I am using on a multiuser linux machine? I want to know whether I am using a lot of memory and possibly inconveniencing others, so I can shut down my processes if necessary.

I've seen in another question that `sa -m` might do it, but I apparently don't have access to that command on this server.

**Edit:** I don't have sudo access, so I can't install stuff. The server is CentOS.

Comment: CentOS5, 6 or 7?

Comment: @jsbillings "CentOS release 5.11 (Final)"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `ps` together with `awk` to find the physical memory usage by a user:

```
ps -U root --no-headers -o rss | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print int(sum/1024) "MB"}'
```

Here it prints memory used by `root` to the output.

Comment: So in my case we can use the environment variable suggested by @Luciano:


`ps -U $USER --no-headers -o rss | awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print int(sum/1024) "MB"}'`

Comment: Yes exactly! Change `root` to whatever user you have in the system.

Comment: I running multiprocessing code, and this comand said that I am using 2TB of RAM =)) while my computer only has 200GB of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I think smem is the better tool in your case.

Install smem and try

```
smem -uk
```

If you are using debian you can install it using:

```
apt-get install smem
```

If you cant install nothing on the server you can try:

```
 ps haux | awk -v user=$USER '$1 ~ user { sum += $4} END { print user, sum; }'
```

Remember that $USER is a environment variable so you don't need to set it.

Comment: What units are the results in - gigabytes? On my current desktop, running that command returns 76, which is hard to interpret as GB (I don't have that much RAM).

Comment: If you are talking about ps haux it is returning the use in percentage.

Comment: I don't have access to smem on the server, but on my localhost I get

`User     Count     Swap      USS      PSS      RSS`

 `user       127   716.0M    11.1G    11.1G    11.9G`

Comment: The other command returns the use in percentage.